# How do you deal with array indices when there's no integer type?

Tags: typescript

Been using Typescript for a year or two now. I love it.

But one thing I don't like is that there is not integer type. For math, integer vs real number makes no difference. A number is a number.

But for array indices, the number must (should?) always be an integer. I don't like the idea that I can't make the compiler catch errors like these:

```
let arr: number[] = []
let number = arr[0.5] // <--- yikes, compiler shouldn't allow this imo
```

Typescript devs, how do you deal with array indices when there is no integer type?

Comment: There is now way to handle this with the TypeScript compiler. Indeed TypeScript only understand `number` type. Eslint don't seems to have such a rule. Best that you can do is to test that `arr[0.5]` is not `undefined`. Also keep in mind that `arr[0.5]` is the same as accessing `arr['0.5']`.